# Django ORM query for a messaging system

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models for an internal messaging app:

```
class MessageThread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(MessageThread)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)

class MessageRecipient(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(MessageThread)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MESSAGE_STATUS, default="unread")
```

For a given user, to get a list of threads I am doing:

```
distinct_threads=MessageThread.objects.filter(messagerecipient__recipient=user)
    .order_by('-message__timestamp').distinct()
```

How would I get rid of all threads with a message that contains the status "deleted" in the ORM? (In other words, I want to get a list of all threads without the thread containing a message with the status="deleted".)

Comment: This is one of the holes in Django's ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a method in a model manager for this:

```
    def get_active_threads(self, user):
        all_threads = MessageRecipient.objects.filter(recipient=user).order_by('-message__timestamp')

        deleted_threads = []
        final_threads = []

        for thread in all_threads:
            if thread.thread not in (deleted_threads or final_threads):
                if thread.status == "deleted":
                    deleted_threads.append(thread.thread)
                else:
                    final_threads.append(thread)

        return final_threads
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either do it in python (as suggested above) or let the DB do the dirty work for you.

You would need to construct a QuerySet containing all threads with a deleted message for a particular user and then a second QuerySet that gets all threads not contained in the first:

```
delthreads = MessageThread.objects.filter(messagerecipient__recipient=user,
    messagerecipient__status='deleted').distinct()
result = MessageThread.objects.filter(messagerecipient_recipient=user)
    .exclude(messagethread_in=delthreads).distinct()
```

However, performance wise (especially on large tables) this will hurt you. Your model needs some restructuring to allow for more efficient queries. Consider:

```
class MessageThread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(MessageThread)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MESSAGE_STATUS, default="unread")
```

If you anticipate you will execute this query often, you could add a cache field to MessageThread which you can update whenever someone deletes a message in that thread:

```
class MessageThread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    dirty = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then, it would be very easy to extract a list of threads with no deleted messages.

```
nondelthreads = MessageThread.objects.filter(message__recipient=user, dirty=True).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick aside, why have you got `thread` as a field within `MessageRecipient`? You can get to the `thread` via the `message`.

Anyhow, you need to use [exclude()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude)

```
# breaking up onto multiple lines for readability, not valid python though
MessageThread.objects.filter(messagerecipient__recipient=user)
.exclude(messagerecipient__status='deleted')
.order_by('-message__timestamp').distinct()
```

Comment: Wouldn't this allow a thread to remain in the query if, for instance, there are 5 messages in a thread and only one of those messages is marked deleted? It needs to remove a thread if **any** message within that thread is deleted, rather than if all are.